# Game Services OAuth2.0 error when testing release SHA-1 authorisation

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-play-services, sha1, google-play-games

I am been trying to set up my game for google play game services. So far I have managed to get a debug SHA-1 authorization to work and sign into the services in my game. Although, I cannot manage to get the release SHA-1 authorization to work. When I tap the sign in button in my app I get the usual sign in and select account options after this screen;
[image]
but once you select your account and it loads it up I get this error message
[image]
and the sign in was unsuccessful.
I have tried almost everything but I don't know what I am doing incorrectly. I have both client ID's correctly entered and linked to the developer console. I am also using firebase in my app if that changes anything. Any help would be appreciated. I can't seem to find this error code anywhere either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to check the suggestion in this thread: [Can't authenticate users, sign in fails](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/1800#issuecomment-310877125)

- Go to `https://console.developers.google.com/` and then choose API manager from menu.
- Then go to credentials of your app (if your app isn't there yet you should add it using the search).
- When you're in credentials of your app just replace SHA-1 certificate line with the one that shown in your App signing (it's in Release management menu of Google Play Console).
- There you'll see app signing certificate info, you need that SHA-1 line from there, then you just replace the one you have in credentials with that one.

Also, based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting), if you are unable to sign players into your game, first make sure that you have followed the instructions to [create your client IDs](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling) and [configure the games services](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/configuring). If you still encounter sign-in errors, check the following items to make sure that your game is set up correctly.

- [Check your metadata tags](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting#check_your_metadata_tags)
- [Check your package name](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting#check_your_package_name)
- [Check the certificate fingerprint](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting#check_the_certificate_fingerprint)
- [Check that test accounts are enabled](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting#check_that_test_accounts_are_enabled)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I was using my apps own SHA-1 instead of the developer consoles signed SHA-1. I just added that SHA-1 to my credentials and it worked. Thanks!